# What's with all the WebSocket errors?

Tags: bug, chat, javascript, web-sockets

I was just chatting in the Tavern when I saw this:

<sub>***click image to enlarge***</sub>
[image]

Eeek! Why are there so many WebSocket errors?

I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.95 (Official Build 213514) m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are running tests on the Web Sockets.

From [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/369825256392761345):

> We are testing some new infrastructure around web sockets, if real-time functionality blips, it will return soon!